# How can i set the size of rows , columns in textField in Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I have this Model

```
summary = models.TextField()
```

But I want to have only  4 rows and 15 columns.

Also if I do that do I need to install database again or not.

Answer (score 146):

`TextField` is a type of field, which when used by a `ModelForm` by default uses the `Textarea` widget. [Fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/) deal with backend storage, [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) with front-end editing.

So you need to specify the widget you want to go with your field. You want to create a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) and specify the `widget` you want to use, per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets):

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
          'summary': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':15}),
        }
```

Comment: Er, no... this is a model field, not a form field.

Comment: I will post a form field equivalent for this below but the answer above is right as it applies to the model.

Comment: Two warnings: the class `MyForm` is missing a colon (:) and it doesn't work in Django 1.8 without explicitly referencing fields in Meta (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28306288) )

Comment: For the latest version of django check out overriding default fields in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 26):

Here is the form specific equivalent for changing the rows/cols attribute to a textarea. Use the forms.Textarea widget and set attrs dictionary values:

```py
class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    auto_email_list = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2, 'cols': 40}))
    notes = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        exclude = ['id']
```

Hope this helps those looking for form specific

Comment: this works for Instance editting in djando 1.11, thanks

Answer (score 16):

If you're using django-crispy-forms, in your `__init__()` function you can access the widget attrs like so:

```
self.fields['summary'].widget.attrs['rows'] = 4
self.fields['summary'].widget.attrs['columns'] = 15
```

I suppose you could set the attrs this way it in a non crispy-form ModelForm, but you may as well do it in your widget definition, as shown above. I just found this post and thought I'd share how I did it with crispyforms.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use jQuery as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").attr({"rows": "4",
                        "cols": "15"
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to work in my case in ModelListView, thanks

Answer (score 3):

First you have to install django widget tweaks by using:

```
pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

Then you have to go to setting.py and add 'widget_tweaks' to installed apps like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'widget_tweaks',
)
```

Then go to your html template and replace this with {{ field }}, to resize your text field:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{{ mytextareafield|attr:"rows:4" | "cols:30" }}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`django-widget-tweaks`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) package makes this quite simple. In your template:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
...
{{ mytextareafield|attr:"rows:3" }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Widget in Meta.
Keep in Mind that **you must add that field in modelform also**

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.CharField()
        
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ()
        widgets = {
            address': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':1, 'cols':15}),
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The first answer may be the right one for the question, but the django-widget-tweaks package is also a great option for changing more attributes, for instance set specific CSS class.

So consider that option if you want to alter another attributes easily.