# Input text field do not show on browser - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I following a book to learn Django, but now I am stuck because I cant render the text field that I should. I am using Django version 1.9 and usually rendering on Firefox.

My django forms.py

```
from django import forms

class TweetForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 1,
'cols': 85}), max_length=160)
    country = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

I have these two html files: base.html and profile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
<html>


<head>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-static navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MyTweets</a>
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right container-fluid">User Profile Page</p>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Footer </p>
    </nav>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--esse extends significa que ele vai entrar no bloco definido no arquivo base.html-->
<!-- primeiro esse profile era apenas pra mostrar os twitters, mas depopis adicionamos o campo de

adicionar um novo twitter, utilizando form, que foi feito no aqquivo <forms class="py"></forms>-->
{% extends "tweets/base.html" %}

<!--definicao dos blocos, ou seja, tera o mesmo header, body ..., o que muda eh o content-->    
{% block content %}
<div class="container" class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
    <!--Form para um novo twitter-->
        <form method="post" action="post/">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.text.errors }}
                {{ form.text }}
            </div>
            {{ form.country.as_hidden }}
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="post">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  

    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>

    <!--loop que mostra os tweets-->
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <!-- ver a logica disso no views-->
        {% for tweet in tweets %}
        <!-- a classe well ou wellbox, da o efeito de insercao-->
        <div class="well">
            <span>{{tweet.text}}</span>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So, the result of rendering this is the image below:

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to this -> `<input type="submit" value="post">` input field in **profile.html** ?? Coz I don't see any other `input` tag. And if that's the `input` tag you are referring to, then its visible on your page as a **button** on which **post** is written. If you want it to be a text input, change the type of the input tag to text instead of submit. Like this -> `<input type="text" value="post">`

Comment: The form,text is a widget defined on my forms.py ...

Comment: Also this is not related to Django. It's part of HTML. So technically the TAGS you linked to this question of yours are incorrect.

Comment: Oh, so you are talking about the Django form? If so, then you'll have to show us your `forms.py`

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi, sorry, I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so Django doesn't allows you to add **attrs** for form fields in case of `forms.Form`

Either you need to use `ModelForm`. Something like this:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
          'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':1, 'cols':85}),
        }
```

But for your use case, I would recommend using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks package like this in your template:

So firstly `pip install django-widget-tweaks`

Now add **django-widget-tweaks** in **installed_apps** in **settings.py** like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'widget_tweaks',
)
```

Now use them ion your templates like this:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
...
{{ form.text|attr:"rows:1"|attr:"cols:85" }}
```

See this -> [How can i set the size of rows , columns in textField in Django Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536373/how-can-i-set-the-size-of-rows-columns-in-textfield-in-django-models)